# Proving a polynomial has a solution in the interval (0,1)

Tags: analysis, polynomials

I have no idea how to start this problem. I am assuming that the Mean Value Theorem is needed in the proof but I am not exactly sure how to apply it to the given polynomial. Any hints/help would be appreciated.

If 
 $ \frac{a_n}{n+1} +  \frac{a_{n-1}}{n} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \frac{a_1}{2} + a_0 = 0 $, 
 prove that the polynomial equation 
 $ a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + a_1x + a_0 = 0$ 
 has a solution in $(0,1)$.

Comment: point $\mapsto$ [root](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialRoots.html) $\;$

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Define $g(x)=\frac{a_n}{n+1}x^{n+1}+\dotsb+\frac{a_1}2x^2+a_0x$ then $g(0)=g(1)=0$,hence by Rolle's theorem there is some $c$ in the interval $(0,1)$ such that $g'(c)=0$ as we want.

Comment: Very simple, sensical solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: the term $\frac{1}{n+1}, \frac 1n,\cdots$ is a hint that you can do integration. Integrate the polynomails on $[0,1]$ and see what happens.